# copy values from array into another different size

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array A [8] = {0};
And another array B[20] = {0};

I want to move all the values from B[12...20] to A[0...8]. How can i exactly change the indices? is there a formula?
So B[12] -->A[0]
B[13] -->A[1]

Thank you.

Comment: Note that `B[20]` is out of bounds. You probably mean `B[12...19]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy). It works for user defined types too:

```
std::copy(B+12, B+20, A);
```

or, in c++11,

```
std::copy(std::next(B,12), std::end(B), std::begin(A));
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use [`std::copy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) here, which will work correctly no matter the type of elements in your arrays (speaking of which, you don't show that type -- the question has invalid syntax).

```
std::copy(B + 12, B + 20, A);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply write a loop

```
int offset = 12;
int lenA = 8;

for(int i=0; i < lenA; i++) {
   A[i] = B[i+offset];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy(A, B + 12, 8 * sizeof(A[0]));` should do the trick.

Assuming A and B are both the same type.

Comment: hi @dunc is there a way to do it using for loop?

Comment: It won't copy memcpy would copy number of bytes. If it is an integer or some other object - byte count would differ

Comment: I'd actually recommend the `std::copy` answer from Jon, since you are using C++.

Comment: I actually wanted to see how I can switch  between the incides using the for loop

Comment: This will only work if the arrays are of basic C compatible types. Use std::copy, it is safer, it indicated the intent better (you are copying elements, NOT memory), and very likely compiles down to a memcpy where is't safe to do so anyway

Comment: Valid points.  Given the question was how to copy one empty array with no type into another I didn't give it enough thought :)